# A CMS for Videos

Tags: content-management-system

I would like to know what is a good CMS that is for videos? Where I can upload videos, feature videos, and the videos have their own page that people can comment on, rate, etc? Can Wordpress achieve this? Or what is a good CMS that can? [free!]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Wordpress can fairly easily become a video site, provided that you upload videos in a blog type form. For each post, there's an option to upload a video, and you can always embed videos as well. Also, since there's an integrated system to allow users to make posts as well, you can have other people uploading too. It's really just a matter of carefully choosing a theme that will work and configuring the site properly to host videos.

The real concern with having a video site isn't the CMS, it's the bandwidth, disk space, and cycles it'll take up on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using the Plone CMS, with a product to choose from http://www.contentmanagementsoftware.info/plone/video

Answer (score 0):

While it's true that WordPress (or really most CMS applications) can be rigged to do what you're talking about if you add each video as a separate post, it's pretty basic functionality.

It sounds like what you're looking for is almost a mini-YouTube site. I can't think of a CMS out there that will do that right out of the box. Fortunately there are add-ons that you can 'plug in' to CMS applications that will provide that functionality for you.

For Joomla (which is open source and free to download), there is a component called hwdVideoShare that contains all of the functionality you mentioned. There is a free version that you can download and install on any Joomla powered web site.

WordPress probably has something similar, but since I only use WP when I absolutely have to (read:when a client insists on using it) I can't say for sure what the equivalent is.

Good luck!

Best,

Cynthia